Android Studio - AGP 8.5.1 - Rebuild project runs Tests as well
In the latest AGP 8.5.1, when we try the option "Rebuild Project" under the "Build" section, Android Studio also performs test tasks. In the previous version of the AGP and Gradle we used, tests were not running with Rebuild.
Is there an option to disable that test task won't run in "Rebuild Project"?
I tried to add a groovy task with the rebuild option - excluding test tasks, but it didn't work, not sure if that is even possible.
We are using the Gradle wrapper: gradle-8.7-bin.zip.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/329145801 it's a new feature

@tim_yates do you know if there is a possibility to disable testing tasks? Thank you for the link.
